# error C2027: use of undefined type 'X509_crl_st'

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

I am migrating OpenSSL to 1.1.1, code compilation is failing with below error :

error C2027: use of undefined type 'X509_crl_st'

I found the typedef of this struct in "\openssl-1.1.1w\include\openssl\ossl_typ.h"

So, I  included this file in our file but still getting same error.

Could anyone please help on this?